# Visual Basic Simple Register new account with access database

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtCreate.Click
        Try
            UsersPasswordsBindingSource.EndEdit()
         UsersPasswordsTableAdapter.Update(UsersPasswordsDataSet.UsersPasswords)
            MsgBox("Data saved")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Error")
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Here my problem is: It replace the old database username and password instead of creating a new. I just want to put the new username and password into access without replacement. Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

because you are not creating  new row

create new row, add it to tableadapter and then **update**

Comment: thx for the comment,is it possible to create new row in the same button? i just want to have register and close button....dont wan add another one for create new row button....